# Asking about $R$-submodules which are not finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n},...]$ the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Find (and explain why) a $R^{R}$-submodule (being $R^R$ the regular module over $R$) which is not finitely generated.

I need help about this issue, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is, I believe, the standard example of the fact that a submodule of a finitely generated module needs not be finitely generated.

**Hint:** The regular module is finitely generated (as it always is for a unital ring) by $1$. We are looking for a submodule (an ideal of $R$, basically) which is not finitely generated. $R$ is a polynomial ring. What kinds of ideals do you have in a polynomial ring? Can you think of one that's not finitely generated?

Comment: Could be a solution consider the submodule K consisting of all polynomials with zero constant term ? Since every polynomial contains only finitely many terms whose coefficients are non-zero, the R-module K is not finitely generated.

Comment: @user725514 That seems like a good idea. And it doesn't matter that polynomials only have finitely many terms; you can't make a finite number of generators generate every degree-1 monomial.